# php & mysql: How to get values between two dates including both of them

Tags: php, mysql

I need to to get values between two dates including both of them.
And is it possible to get values of one date if user selects both dates as same?

I have date column as date and time
i am using code as :

```
select * 
from tbl_issue 
where issue_on>='$date_search' 
    and issue_on<='$date_search1' 
    and item_name='$item_id';

$date_search1 = substr($date_search1,8,2).substr($date_search1,4,4).substr($date_search1,0,4);
```

The result of this i am getting is between these dates but i wants including both of them.

Help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can change your query to this. This will get you the expected result:

```
select * from tbl_issue where (issue_on between '$date_search' and '$date_search1') and item_name='$item_id';
```

Comment: Dear I want both dates to be included and it will not work in case user selects both dates as same.

Comment: I want two values of dates 2013-04-01 and 2013-04-10 and this query gets values of 2013-04-01 but not getting values of 2013-04-10 it takes values from 2013-04-01 to 2013-04-09

Comment: Do you want all the data between these 2 dates or you just want data of these 2 dates?

Comment: I want data of 2013-04-01 to 2013-04-10 both dates included a

Comment: No, you would be doing some mistake, this query will get you the data from 2013-04-01 to 2013-04-10. Can you echo the query and check what's there in $date_search1?

Comment: Yes in i have echo it ,bro in $date_select1 if i select 2013-04-10 it gets data before this date not including this

Comment: Just echo that query and paste me the resulted query here.